# How do you theme a Quiz Question?

Tags: theming, quiz

I have a True/False Quiz module question that I want to theme the output on...basically wrap the question with some extra stuff. I grabbed the truefalse-answering-form.tpl.php file from the module folder, copied it to my theme folder and made the needed changes, but my overriden theme file isn't being loaded.

I cleared the caches and still no luck.

Devel Themer isn't really providing me with useful info either...

Has anyone successfully themed a Quiz Module Question? Is there something extra that needs to be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override quiz-single-question-node.tpl.php