# How to theme a Quiz in Drupal 7? - part 2

Tags: theming, quiz

Trying to customize the look and feel of my quizzes in D7 - and getting overwhelmed. I have the Skeleton base theme installed.

Calling this Part 2 because - this is an extension of [How to theme a quiz in D7?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/57345/how-to-theme-a-quiz-in-d7).

Help sought: Which CSS files specifically to target to change the Quiz Take page?

I have added the **quiz-single-question-node.tpl.php** file - and rendered the **$question_node->content['body']**. And now the quiz works fine... (but without my desired changes yet).

My problem is that the **'body'** from above is a fully formed HTML Form of the quiz question. SO, where exactly should I look to:
a. change this body to perhaps add a CSS class?
b. where should I add the CSS class itself?

Would really appreciate some detailed hand-holding.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\sites\all\modules\quiz\Quiz.css --> this is the place to change.

CSS class definition to be created for: "quiz-question-body" - this is for the question itself.